# Create a table and default column value to a received variable parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a MSSQL stored procedure.

I receive a table valued parameter (`@accountPropsTVP`) and a single variable (`@accountID`) from the C# server.

`@accountPropsTVP` has 2 columns:

- `valueTypeID int`
- `value varchar(max)`

Note: I'm never sure how many rows will be in this table.

`@accountID` is an `int`.

**I need to merge everything received into one table, so that it ends up looking like so:**

`@temporaryTable`:

- `@accountID` (always the same for all rows)
- `valueTypeID`
- `value`

**Below is what I have tried, but I get an error:**

> Msg 112, Level 15, State 4, Procedure `insertAccountProps`, Line 20
> Variables are not allowed in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertAccountProps 
    -- Received parameters
    @accountID int,
    @accountPropsTVP accountPropsTVP READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    -- declare new table
    DECLARE @accountPropsTemp TABLE
    (
        accountID int not null DEFAULT (@accountID),
        valueTypeID int not null, 
        value varchar(max) not null
    )
    
    -- insert received TVP into new temp table, so that we can manipulate it (tvp's are read only :( )
    INSERT INTO @accountPropsTemp
    SELECT *
    FROM @accountPropsTVP


    -- select all from TVP and add it into temp table created above
    INSERT INTO dbo.accountsProps
    SELECT *
    FROM @accountPropsTemp
END
GO
```

Maybe there's a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: You did not post the CREATE TABLE statement .... it sounds like you may need dynamic SQL but without seeing your create table statement I can't be sure what the solution is.

Comment: He did post it, it's the `DECLARE @accountPropsTemp TABLE`.

Comment: Error wording threw me off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
DECLARE @accountPropsTemp TABLE
    (
        accountID int not null DEFAULT (@accountID),
        valueTypeID int not null, 
        value varchar(max) not null
    )
```

You're assigning a variable as a default value which as the error message clearly states is not allowed.

The best option for this is to change your syntax to:

```
DECLARE @accountPropsTemp TABLE
(
    accountID int not null,
    valueTypeID int not null, 
    value varchar(max) not null
)


INSERT INTO
    @accountPropsTemp
SELECT 
    @AccountID
    ,ValueTypeID
    ,Value
FROM 
    @accountPropsTVP
```

Comment: I dont know where Col1, Col2, and Col3 are coming from

Comment: @sunfish Well you didn't tell us the column names in your table variable so I put placeholders in.

Comment: I don't mean to sound facetious, but please look at my question again and let me know if I didn't tell you the column names.

Comment: @sunfish You did not tell us the column names for your custom table type `@accountPropsTVP`.  I don't make the presumption that source and target column names are the same.  I have no way to know what columns are in the `accountPropsTVP` table type.

Comment: Is this what you mean? Verbatim, from the question:

@accountPropsTVP has 2 columns:
- valueTypeID int
- value varchar(max)

Comment: @sunfish And I'm a fool, because I read the code and not the comments above :) Apologies!

Comment: @sunfish Fixed to use column names

Comment: @sunfish "I tried to implement his answer and it didn't work. Do you think I would waste my time and others' trolling my own SO question before trying to figure out his answer on my own? Maybe you should come out from under that bridge." then JNK says updated with column names. Then you thanks that worked. Hahaha! Brilliant.